# UIButton doesn't set center

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button I added manually on the storyboard. I would like when the screen loads, to this button sets its center with the coordination I give to it by

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    NSLog(@"Will Layout");
    CGPoint buttonPoint;
    buttonPoint.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 50;
    buttonPoint.x = self.view.frame.size.width /2;

    [menuButton setCenter:buttonPoint];
}
```

But nothing changes, the button stays still on the place I first dragged it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have auto layout on (it's on by default). Even if you don't add constraints, the system, will add them for you. When using auto layout, you should not set any frames. You need to change the position by adjust the constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple for both the modern AutoLayout based and old legacy Springs&Struts based layout management approach.

**AUTOLAYOUT**

You simply set up two constraints that will keep the button in the horizontal middle and in the vertical middle minus 50 points up.
[image]

**SPRINGS & STRUTS**

You will make sure the button is set to be in the center by setting the autoresizing mask properly in the Size inspector. Then in code, in view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, you will fix the 50 points offset.

(Some might suggest viewWillLayoutSubviews, but let's not complicate it for now.)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x,
                                   self.button.frame.origin.y - 50,
                                   self.button.frame.size.width,
                                   self.button.frame.size.height);

/// other code....
}
```

[image]